# How to change ANDROID_NDK_ROOT and COCOS2DX_ROOT?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

Hello Everyone,
         While installing and configuring cocos2d and android ndk I am getting some problem and the problem that i have estimated is that the default path for android_ndk and cocos2d are taking cygdrive/e/android/android-ndk-r8/ndk.(as reference i am using this link http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-setup-cocos2d-x-windows-and-android/)

Let me provide the command prompt image:
[image]

Thanks.